# Community Ads for CiviCRM

Tags: discussion

As a beta site we cannot host our own ads. But we **can** post ads on other sites. Good targets would be the Drupal and WP sites (not Joomla they are still in beta).

Please post below ideas for image ads in the following format:

- The image that you create must be 220 x 250 pixels
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

Once we've agreed on an ad image, we can post them to the community-ad threads on [Drupal](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/community-promotion-ads-2015) and [WP](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/community-promotion-ads-2015).